# Validate objects in many-to-many relationship in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models `Group` and `User`. I have a ManyToManyField in `Group` referencing `User`. I also have an intermediate model `GroupUser` storing additional data (date for assigning and type of membership) to the many-to-many relationship.

I have a page `/groups/group-<group_id>/create-user/` at which I add users to the group. My problem is that if a user is created as type 1, he cannot be assigned to other groups. How can I validate that the user is not assigned to other groups if a relationship already exists with the specific user and type 1?

I'm using a CreateView

```
class GroupUserCreateView(CreateView):
    model = GroupUser
    fields = ['user', 'type']
    template_name = "group_user_create_form.html"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.group = get_object_or_404(Group, id=self.kwargs['group_id'])
        return super(GroupUserCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.group = self.group
        return super(GroupUserCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('group_user_list', kwargs={'group_id': self.group.id})
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about CreateView, but my guess, overwrite `get_form` and adjust the queryset on the on the `user` field.

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    create_form = super(GroupUserCreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
    create_form.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.exclude(groupuser__type=1)
    return create_form
```

Comment: It almost worked but I am only concerned with those users in which `Membership.type = 1`. It should still be possible to add those users who does not have any membership with type=1. Is it possible? I'm using Django 1.8

Comment: I adjusted my answer. We know show all users, which don't have a groupuser__type=1 set. In the end, keep adjusting the `QuerySet` till its right.